# has_many_through association adding multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_many association using checkboxes which works well with `statement` and `identity`.

The problem I'm facing is to how best associate the Phase table with the Identity table and still link it to the statement form. So for each `statement` there can be many `identities` and for each of those `identities` i would like to associate a `phase` using a radio button tag.

```
class Indicator < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :statement, required: false
  belongs_to :identity, required: false
  belongs_to :phase, required: false
end

class Statement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, required: false
  has_many :indicators   
  has_many :identities, :through => :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :identities
end

class Identity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators   
  has_many :statements, :through => :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :statements
  has_many :phases, :through => :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phases
end

class Phase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators
  has_many :identities, :through => :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :identities
end
```

Then in my form:

```
<%= form_with(model: statement, local: true) do |form| %>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <% hidden_field_tag "statement[identity_ids][]", nil %>
   <% Identity.all.each do |b| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= check_box_tag "statement[identity_ids][]", b.id, @statement.identity_ids.include?(b.id) %></td>
     <td><%= b.description %></td>
     <td>CODE FOR PHASES</td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is not working hear? do you have an error message or more info on what is not working?

Comment: No error message, just not saving to the database.

Comment: there is an error message. You are not displaying it, so you should set a breakpoint and then display the error message in the `rails console` by doing `@yourobject.errors.full_messages`

Comment: Please add controller's code. Also, if you have  an object, it is always better to use `form_for` . Also, share the whole for for better understanding

Comment: Thanks @Aakanksha I have added more code. I am using form_with as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, there is no requirement for `has_many :phases, :through => :indicators`. `has_many :phases` should work just fine. Also, why loop over and display the checkboxes and radio buttons when we have method `collection_radio_buttons` and `method collection_check_boxes`

Also if uyou want to display the phase of an identity, you should be using `b.phases.all.each` instead of `<% Phase.all.each do |b| %>`

I'm not sure if you've implemented this yet and are looking only for a cleaner code. If you're facing issues to actually save the records, please share the error to understand better.

Comment out any issues and i'll be happy to help.

Comment: Appreciate your help on this @Aakanksha. I have updated my question to hopefully help you with a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve.